# How can we restrict Youtube player forward seek in Android using YoutubePlayer API?

Tags: android, youtube-api

While playing videos in YouTube player I need to restrict the user from seeking forward but he can seek backward. How can we achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

YoutubePlayer API has not this possibility, but you can do the trick. The logic is next: you can listen the played position of the player with `mYouTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis()` and remember the last played position. When user will make the seek, you should calculate the difference between last played position and `getCurrentTimeMillis()`. And if difference more than needed time, just set the maximum available time to seek by `mYouTubePlayer.seekToMillis(max_available_time_to_seek)`